# Is there a way to get multiple rows in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I am currently working on a project where I am required to make a list of entries from a SQL table where the id in the column is the same.

Here is the table:

```
+------+------+
|name  |id    |
+------+------+
|Ex1   |1     |
+------+------+
|Ex2   |1     |
+------+------+
|Ex3   |2     |
+------+------+
```

I have tried the code below:

```php
$id = '1';
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id = '$id'";
$data2=mysqli_query($link,$query2);
$row2=mysqli_fetch_array($data2);
$name = $row2["name"];
```

however that code only returns Ex2 and I would like it to return all the names with the id I specify in $id

Comment: *"however that code only returns Ex2 and I would like it to return all the names with the id I specify in $id"* - What "id" are you asking to search for? If you're telling it to search for "Ex2", then you got what you asked for.

Comment: *"I am required to make a list of entries from a SQL table where the id in the column is the same."* - How can they be the same? All of your data is unique. Edit: Ok, so now you've edited.

Comment: I have read your comment and read back my question, I hope that my edit has better helped you to understand what I'm asking

Comment: A: you need to use a loop (either `foreach` or `while`) and possibly `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: I am sorry, however I have no idea as to how to how I would incorporate this, I am learning as a student. I have looked at each of those and neither seem to obviously fit in to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over successful results with a [`while`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)  loop.

```
while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($data2)){
// echo $name = is valid syntax.
    echo $name = $row2["name"] . "<br>" . "\n";
// The \n used will show clean HTML in source.
}
```

Side note: You might have to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Plus, use a prepared statement for this as it's safer, since you could be leaving yourself open to SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: I appreciate your help! This was a school assignment and I got stuck on it! It worked, and next semester we will be securing our code against injection

Comment: @AndrewSturgis19 You're most welcome. I am glad to have been of help. You stand at being ahead of the class when it comes time to help protect against SQL injection ;-) *Cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `foreach` loop to iterate over all the results fetched from the database.

Besides, you should use prepared statements with parameter binding.

The correct code would look something like this:

```
$id = '1';
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

foreach ($result as $row2) {
    $name = $row2["name"];
    // do something with the name
    echo $name.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or if you want you can collect all results in an array.

```
$allNames = [];
foreach ($result as $row2) {
    $allNames[] = $row2["name"];
}
```